# Ordering equal rows except the last element with respect to the last column in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

I have a question on a piece of code in Matlab. Suppose we have a matrix 
`A` of dimension `mx4`

```
 A=[ 2 3 4 |1
     2 3 4 |0
     1 1 1 |0
     1 1 1 |1
     9 1 0 |0
     9 1 0 |0
     9 1 0 |1]
```

I want to order the rows with the first three elements of the row equal with respect to the fourth column in descending order. Hence, I want to get

```
 B=[ 2 3 4 |1
     2 3 4 |0
     1 1 1 |1
     1 1 1 |0
     9 1 0 |1
     9 1 0 |0
     9 1 0 |0]
```

Comment: What I am thinking is if the rows are equal then what good will reordering them w.r.t the fourth column bring out ? As in what are you trying to use this for ?

Comment: once they are reordered I want to keep only the first repetition with "unique"

Comment: @user3285148 why not just use `unique(A, 'rows')` if that's your end goal?

Comment: Unique keeps the first equal row

Comment: I feel that this is an overkill for the bigger problem you have at hand. Please explain what you are trying to achieve and there may be straightforward ways to get that. Convoluted or tricky code would be prone to bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to create an M x 2 matrix that you can sort using `sortrows`. `sortrows` sorts the first column and then uses the second column to settle any ties. The first column will be an index used to represent unique combinations of the first three columns of `A`.

For your example data, the first column would look like this.

```
[~, ~, inds] = unique(A(:,1:3), 'rows', 'stable');

inds =

     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
     3
     3
```

Then, the second column is the column that you want to sort (your 4th column).

```
cat(2, inds, A(:,4))

   1     1
   1     0
   2     0
   2     1
   3     0
   3     0
   3     1
```

Now we want to use `sortrows` on this and sort the first column in ascending order and the second column in descending order.

```
sorted = sortrows(cat(2, inds, A(:,4)), [1 -2])

   1     1
   1     0
   2     1
   2     0
   3     1
   3     0
   3     0
```

This second column corresponds to the desired 4th column that you've shown in `B`. So let's simply concatenate it with the first three columns of `A` to create `B`.

```
B = cat(2, A(:,1:3), sorted(:,2))

   2     3     4     1
   2     3     4     0
   1     1     1     1
   1     1     1     0
   9     1     0     1
   9     1     0     0
   9     1     0     0
```

---

### Summary

So bringing that all together we get the following.

```
[~, ~, inds] = unique(A(:,1:3), 'rows', 'stable');
sorted = sortrows(cat(2, inds, A(:,4)), [1 -2]);
B = cat(2, A(:,1:3), sorted(:,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Se below a similar approach using `splitapplay` (Introduced in R2015b)

```
A=[ 2 3 4 1
   2 3 4 0
   1 1 1 0
   1 1 1 1
   9 1 0 0
   9 1 0 0
   9 1 0 1];

% Map first 3 columns to a single value
aux = str2num(strcat(num2str(A(:,1)),num2str(A(:,2)),num2str(A(:,3))));

% Find groups
G = sort(findgroups(aux));

% Sort groups of same value in descending order with respect to column 4
sorted = splitapply(@(x,y) {[dec2base(x,10)-'0',sort(y,'descend')]}, aux, A(:,4), G );
sorted = cell2mat(sorted)

sorted =

   2     3     4     1
   2     3     4     0
   1     1     1     1
   1     1     1     0
   9     1     0     1
   9     1     0     0
   9     1     0     0
```